# Recaptcha Error: I/O Exception: Name in certificate does not match host name

Tags: coldfusion, recaptcha, coldfusion-9

So I'm trying to get ReCaptcha to work on ColdFusion (full source code below). I tried using both get/post and I get the same error.

```
I/O Exception: Name in certificate `google.com' does not match host name `www.google.com'
```

[image: CFHTTP Error]

I converted my code to PHP (full source code below) and it works fine. The only difference is that the PHP code is using get method only.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? Thanks for the help.

**Coldfusion code:**

```
<cfif StructKeyExists(Form, "submit")>
    <cfset googleurl = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify" />
    <cfset recaptchasecret = "secret-key-here" />
    <cfset recaptcha = FORM["g-recaptcha-response"] >
    <cfset remoteip = CGI["remote_addr"] />

    <!---post method--->
    <!---<cfhttp url="#googleurl#" method="post" resolveURL="yes">
        <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="secret" value="#recaptchasecret#" />
        <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="response" value="#recaptcha]#" />
        <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="remoteip" value="#remoteip#" />
    </cfhttp>--->

    <!---get method--->
    <cfhttp url="#googleurl#?secret=#recaptchasecret#&response=#recaptcha#&remoteip=#remoteip#" method=get/>

    <cfdump var="#cfhttp#"><hr>
    <cfabort>
</cfif>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Google recapcha demo - Codeforgeek</title>
        <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Google reCAPTHA Demo</h1>
        <form id="comment_form" action="test.cfm" method="post">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Type your email" size="40"><br><br>
            <textarea name="comment" rows="8" cols="39"></textarea><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post comment"><br><br>
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="site-key-here"></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**PHP code:**

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        var_dump($_POST);

        $googleurl = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
        $secretKey = "secret-key-here";
        $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

        $response=file_get_contents($googleurl."?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);

        $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);

        var_dump($responseKeys);
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Google recapcha demo - Codeforgeek</title>
        <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Google reCAPTHA Demo</h1>
        <form id="comment_form" action="test.php" method="post">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Type your email" size="40"><br><br>
            <textarea name="comment" rows="8" cols="39"></textarea><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post comment"><br><br>
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="site-key-here"></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a SSL issue - java is not able to connect to "www.google.com" properly. As a temporary workaround, use `<cfset googleurl = "https://google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify" />`. But definitely update java's cert store as well.

Comment: You should definitely use the ssl url and with POST. As it is you are exposing your secret key.